# AggregateResult to a single integer

Tags: soql, list

I'm trying to query a custom object to get the sum of a currency field into a integer value so I can pass it to a visualforce page gauge component. I'm stuck on the query. I can get the values in a list but I cannot seem to sum the field.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults =
[select sum(convertCurrency(amount__c)) sum FROM Actuals__c Where amount__c != null AND ISO_Goal__r.OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];    
Integer sumAmount = groupedResults[0].get('sum');
```

I keep getting Illegal assignment from List Actuals__c to List AggregateResult no matter how I do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is described in the [Querying Currency Fields in Multi-currency Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm) documentation:

> You can’t convert the result of an aggregate function into the user’s
>   currency by calling the convertCurrency() function. If a query
>   includes a GROUP BY or HAVING clause, currency data returned by using
>   an aggregate function, such as SUM() or MAX(), is in the org’s default
>   currency.

So the assignment will work if you remove the `convertCurrency` function from it.

You can then do your own conversion by querying the `CurrencyType` or `DatedConversionRate` objects for the rates.

Also the summed value will be a `Decimal`:

```
Decimal sumAmount = (Decimal) groupedResults[0].get('sum');
```

but if you really want an integer:

```
Integer sumAmountAsInteger = sumAmount.intValue();
```

Comment: this was helpful, the convertCurrency was stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting mentioned error because you can not assign AggregateResult  into integer variable.

- Please try doing following thing:

  ```
  for(AggregateResult objTEMP : [SELECT sum(amount__c) FROM Actuals__c WHERE amount__c != null AND   ISO_Goal__r.OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()])
  {  
    SumInInteger= (Integer)objTEMP.get('expr0');
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [select sum(convertCurrency(amount__c)) FROM Actuals__c Where amount__c != null AND ISO_Goal__r.OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
             if(groupedResults.size()>0 ){ 
                 if(Integer.valueOf(groupedResults[0].get('expr0'))!=null){
                     Integer sumAmount=Integer.valueOf(groupedResults[0].get('expr0'));
                 }
            }
```

try this one. hope it will help you.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained the difference between the code you provided, and the code that the OP (original poster) currently has. The key thing here is that the expression `groupedResults[0].get('expr0')` returns a result of the generic `Object` type. To store that result in an `Integer` variable, we need to do some type casting. This can be done like `Integer sumAmount = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('expr0')`, or like `Integer sumAmount = Integer.valueOf(groupedResults[0].get('expr0'))`

Comment: yes type cast needed and i did that too.. : Integer.valueOf(groupedResults[0].get('expr0')). this is how i do type cast in apex. and its working for me. used to get total of the amount and convert to integer and i used the same what i send u (different query).